# To get the skewness and kurtosis directly from probability density function or histogram

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

This is my first question here. Please understand even if my question is not very clear.

I have tried to calculate skewness and kurtosis directly from probability density function (PDF) without knowing the original data.

I have many data sets and I have made PDFs from these data set and I averaged these into one PDF.

My purpose is to find the skewness and kurtosis of this averaged PDF. Actually I have tried this with computational language of Python. However, I realized that this is mathmatical problem rather than programing language problem.

I know that it may be very difficult or impossible to get the moments without original data set.

Is there any possible solution for this issue such as back calculation from PDF to original data?

Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

Thank you,

Hoonill

Comment: Skewness is defined as $E\left[\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{3}\right]=\frac{\mu_{3}-3\mu\sigma^{2}-\mu^{3}}{\sigma^{3}}$ where $\mu_{3}=E[X^{3}]$ (i.e. third moment) as seen from here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness)

Comment: Thank you for answer user159813. Yes, you are right. as you defined, to get the moments such as skewness and kurtosis, I need X in your equation. However, my problem is that I don't have X, because those are removed over the averaging process of PDFs. Only things I have are bins and probability densities at each bin. Do you think that it is possible to get skewness and kurtosis directly from a PDF, not from original data set?

Comment: well if you have pdf, $f(x)$, then $\mu_{3}=E(X^{3})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{3}f(x)dx$ and $\mu=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$ and $\sigma^{2}=E(X^{2})-\mu^{2}$ where $E(X^{2})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}f(x)dx$

Comment: Are you saying that you have an empirical pdf/cdf?

Comment: Im just a little confused to if you had the data sets, why couldn't use just make the estimators for $E(X^{3})$, $\mu$ and $\sigma^{2}$ from this data

Comment: I am not sure that I understand correctly. So, to get the skewness, I need to know E(X^3). In the equation for E(X^3), small x would be a bin number for PDF? Thank you.

Comment: Also I would post this question also in stat exchange (Cross Validated) because many of those members are very familiar with taking data and calculating these estimators (of skewness, kurtosis, etc)

Comment: Ah.. my explanation was not very clear. Yes, I had data sets for PDF. But I made PDFs with these data sets and averaged these PDFs to one PDF. So, I would like to know the shape of this averaged PDF qualitatively with skewness and kurtosis. The problem is that this averaged PDF doesn't have original data because it is just generated from averaging PDFs not from data. Is it clear? Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how would you calculate the skewness if someone just gave you a histogram

Comment: Yes, I would like to know moments from histogram or PDF without knowing data information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a closed form pdf, you can calculate the skewness from your data alone. (Without even bothering with an estimation of the pdf which will likely lead to high level of error).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Sample_skewness

Using a method of moments estimator of skewness you can calculate:

$\hat\gamma = \frac{(\frac{1}{n}*\sum_{k=1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})^3)}{[\frac{1}{n-1}*\sum_{k=1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})]^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Where $\overline{x}$ is your sample mean.

To answer your this other question of yours:

> Is there any possible solution for this issue such as back calculation from PDF to original data?

You could generate a large sample from your newly calculated PDF, and calculate the skewness using the metric above, but you would be adding a lot of variability and error.

Similarly, for the kurtosis, you can use the following statistic

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis#Sample_kurtosis

$\hat\beta = \frac{(\frac{1}{n}*\sum_{k=1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})^4)}{[\frac{1}{n-1}*\sum_{k=1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})]^{2}} - 3$

In order to simulate a sample, you need to take your empirical pdf and convert it to a cdf. Once you do that, you will want to create an inverse of your cdf.

If you use python to make a very large sample (the larger the better) of Uniform Random variables from $0$ to $1$, and input them into your inverse CDF, you will have a generated a random sample from your empirical PDF.

From there you can use the statistics above.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you janeslmore, according to your answer, it is not very possible to calculate data without errors and variability directly from PDF. Do I understand correctly? Anyhow, it sounds that it is not possible to get moments directly from the PDF not knowing data.. Thnak you.

Comment: @Isaac, you may gain an estimate from your empirical pdf but it will be an extremely rough estimate. What you can do is simulate a (very) large sample from your pdf and then calculate using the functions above. I'll modify my answer, one moment.

Comment: Thank you very much jameselmore, you are very helpful.